# Angular Realtime Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Need help on how to use angular with firebase for realtime data,

**what i have done** 
-I have done all installed and imported the firebase sdk 
-Configured the environment file with the firebase api

**what i want as a result** 
-I want to post the form input to my forebase realtime storage 
-Read and write the input data in my angular app

**result im getting** 
if i submit the form nothing really happens in my browser console and firebase console.

Please im now learning and would be glad for an assistance and correction.

source **https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write**

send.component.ts

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="this.authService.wire_Transfer" novalidate>
        <div class="authBlock2">
          <span style="color: brown;">Enter details for Wire transfer</span>
          <div class="formGroup">
            <input type="text" class="formControl" matInput placeholder="Enter Recipient Name "
               name="recipient" />
          </div>
           <div class="formGroup">
            <input type="text" class="formControl" matInput placeholder="Enter Recipint Bank "
              name="bank" />
          </div>
          <div class="formGroup">
            <input type="text" class="formControl" placeholder="Account Number" 
               name="account" />
          </div>
          <div class="formGroup">
            <input type="text" class="formControl" matInput placeholder="Enter Amount "
               name="amount" />
          </div>          
          <div class="formGroup">
            <input type="text" class="formControl" placeholder="Enter your PIN" 
            name="pin" #pin = "ngModel"/> />
          </div>                        
          <div class="formGroup">
            <button mat-raised-button data-toggle="modal" type="submit" >sen</button>

          </div>
        </div>

      </form>
```

auth.service.ts

```
Transfer(userId, name, bank, account, amount,) {
  firebase.database().ref('transfer/' + userId).set({
    name: name,
    bank: bank,
    account : account,
    amount: amount
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you need help with? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: im glad your reaching up to my aid @robsiemb, i think i have edited my post a bit, and by the way all i want to do is read and read with firebase realtime storage  with angular